# Hierarchy of preferences for property in Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

Is it possible to set up automapper so that if the result of a MapFrom lambda is null/throws a NRE it will look at a different source. My current requirement is very basic so I've been able to do this:

```
.ForMember(a=>a.CountryOfRisk, m=>m.MapFrom(a=>(a.CountryOfRisk??a.Issuer.CountryOfRisk).CountryCode))
```

But really what I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
a=>a.CountryOfRisk, m=>m.MapFrom(a=>a.CountryOfRisk.CountryCode)
                        .Coalesce(a=>a.Issuer.CountryOfRisk.CountryCode))
```

This would mean that I could create a whole set of items which would fill the output field in a nice, config based, easy to read formatted.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this custom resolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<Source, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(Source source)
    {
        return source.CountryOfRisk ?? source.Issuer.CountryOfRisk;
    }
}

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
   cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryOfRisk, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers
(`IValueResolver` deprecated? `ValueResolver` should work).

Comment: Thanks. That'll be useful for more complex items but I was looking for something a little more built-in that would just allow me to set a precedence  order and choose the first non-null/non-exceptiony answer. Maybe I should stop being lazy and build it myself and submit it!